# Wordpress: check if last visited page was homepage?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, visited

I'm fairly new to Wordpress, and really need some help on the PHP bit. On my wordpress pages (Let's call it Page A), I want to call a jQuery animation, but **only** if the visitor clicked a from my wordpress home page to get to Page A.

So just to be clear, how can I call a jQuery animation on page A **given that** the previous page was the homepage?

I wanted to use is_home() to test the page the visitor came *from*. But as far as I understand, is_home() can only be used to test if the *current* page is the homepage.

Is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use History object it has `back` method and you can check if it returns URL of your homepage

The other option is to use cookies on all your pages

```
$.cookie("previousPage", window.location.href, {path:"/"});
```

and then check on PageA

```
if($.cookie("previousPage") == 'yourhomepage') {
   //call animation
}
```

notice: 
  $.cookie is available if you use jquery cookie plugin which can be found [here](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

useful links:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history
- https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer
- https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Comment: Just note, this is just as unrealiable as http referrers. Cookies, like http referrers can be disabled.

Comment: 80 port can be blocked as well. How many users blocks Javascript 1%? HTTP_REFERER can be also removed from server's response. I assume in this answer that user has JavaScript enabled moreover if he doesn't then animation won't work as well. If user blocks cookies then he agrees that page won't have it's 100% functionality and users who know what they do will expect it IMO.

Comment: That's okay! This check is just whether to run an animation or not. It is not crucial to the webpage's functionality at all :)

Answer (score 0):

The WordPress PHP function `get_home_url()` gives you the URL of your home page ([see documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_home_url)). Then in the JavaScript you can use `document.referrer` to compare with:

```
var home_page = '<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>';
if(home_page == document.referrer) {
  //Animate with jQuery, or whatever it is you want to do.
}
```

You can also get the previous page in PHP using `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`. Wheter you use JavaScript or PHP the information might not be reliable since it comes from the browser. But if it ain't important that it's right every single time it is good enough.

Please note that this won't work if you for some reason have single quotes (`'`) in your homepage URL.

Comment: Thank you very much! 99% sure this reply is exactly what I hoped for!

Comment: On second thought, it seems document.referrer is showing up empty, and I can't seem to figure out why. Does that have to do with that it is coming from an internal link?